# Concatenate two PCRE regex, one with unicode characters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to write a regex for phone numbers. The first pattern uses english numbers and the second uses persian numbers. How do concatenate these patterns using `|`?

```
   $pattern1 = '/^(\d{4})?\s?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$/';
   $pattern2 = '/^([\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{4})?\s?[\x{0661}-\x{0669}]{1}[\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{6}$/u';
```

This doesn't work:

```
if (preg_match("($pattern1)|($pattern2)", $phone_number))...
```

And prints this warning:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|'
```

I'm also not sure whether the `/u` delimiter should be placed at the end of second pattern and each subpattern(pattern1 and pattern2) should have their delimiters OR whole concatenated pattarn should have only one delimiter(e.g`/pattern1|pattern2/u`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match` is considering the `(` and `)` as being the delimiters of the regex, while it's not and since `|` comes immediately after, that's why it's saying that `|` is an unknown modifier.

Try using this:

```
$pattern1 = '^(\d{4})?\s?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$';
$pattern2 = '^([\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{4})?\s?[\x{0661}-\x{0669}]{1}[\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{6}$';

if (preg_match("/" . $pattern1 . "|" . $pattern2 . "/u", $phone_number))
```

Notice that I'm placing the delimiters after concatenating the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use two separate preg_match-statements with || in the if clause. The alternative is to rewrite both the regexp strings to combine it into one correct one, which includes a lot more than concatenating them.